# create a service for an existing container in swarm mode in azure

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, swarm, azure-load-balancer

Note: am new to docker/swarm.

I've created a WordPress/mysql containers in a docker swarm mode running on Azure as per https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/.

The cluster was created as per https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/

here is my dockerfile:

```
======================
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
=======================
```

as per official documentation, I can publish ports using `--published` flag, however, I need to know how to include that in Dockerfile.

---

Running apps
You can now start creating containers and services.

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

You can run websites too. Ports exposed with --publish are automatically exposed through the platform load balancer:

```
$ docker service create --name nginx --publish published=80,target=80 nginx
```

Once up, find the DefaultDNSTarget output in either the AWS or Azure portals to access the site.

---

Using docker ps, I can see that it is listening on 0.0.0.0:8000->80, however, without a service, it will not automatically create an azure load balance rule to the container.

```
swarm-manager000000:~/compose$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
8c94587acd97        wordpress:latest                                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp      compose_wordpress_1
aff61e0022a8        mysql:5.7                                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp       compose_db_1
5d2fdb3d75c4        docker4x/l4controller-azure:18.09.2-ce-azure1   "loadbalancer run --…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                    editions_controller
d5f0a8a91f66        docker4x/meta-azure:18.09.2-ce-azure1           "metaserver -iaas_pr…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          10.0.0.4:9024->8080/tcp   meta-azure
93c6571b6ee6        docker4x/guide-azure:18.09.2-ce-azure1          "/entry.sh"              2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                    editions_guide
b6cad5676b10        docker4x/logger-azure:18.09.2-ce-azure1         "python /server.py"      2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:514->514/udp      editions_logger
d2a74fe21751        docker4x/agent-azure:18.09.2-ce-azure1          "supervisord --confi…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                    agent
swarm-manager000000:~/compose$
```

If, for example, I tried to create a service that is mapped to a new image i.e: nginx. this will immediately create an inbound rule in the Azure load balancer.

```
$ docker service create --name nginx --publish published=80,target=80 nginx
```

Please advise of how to map the service to the existing WordPress container, or how to update the Dockerfile to create the service and use `--published`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience that maps the docker service to an existing container. As I know, it just does the same in the swarm as `docker run` command. You can take a look at the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408493/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-service-and-docker-container) of them.

If you really like to map the service to a container, I suggest the [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes) than Docker Swarm in Azure, it's more manageable to you for the service and container. It can map the service to the container no matter it's existing one or creates a new one.

For the issue to publish the port. You can achieve it by using the parameter `--publish` in the `docker run` command like this:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image
```

Or you can do it in the compose file like this:

```
ports:
       - "8000:80"
```

But you cannot publish the port in the Dockerfile, you just can tell the container which port the application listen to by using `EXPOSE`. Take a look at [Expose vs publish: Docker port commands explained simply](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/expose-vs-publish-docker-port-commands-explained-simply-434593dbc9a3), then you will know it.