# Why use docker service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408493/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-service-and-docker-container) question illustrates the theoretical differences between `docker run` and `docker service`.

What I don't understand is when would one need to use the exact same container replicated multiple times (as per the [Docker documentation example](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/))?
There, they run the same web app replicated 5 times.

Is deployment on Kubernetes (for example) a potential use case, where the developer does not want to centralize the app on one host, in order to make it more resilient, hence why 5 replicas are created?

To understand, can someone please please with an example use case, where the `docker service` is useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`swarm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) is an orchestrator just like `kubernetes`. `docker service` deploys services to `swarm` just as you deploy your services to `kubernetes` using `kubectl`.

`swarm` is essentially built-in primitive orchestrator. One possible case for replicas is running a proxy that directs requests to proper containers. You could expose multiple machines and have one take place of another in case another fails. Or any other high availability case you could think of.

Your question could be rephrased as "What's the difference between running a single container and running containers in a cluster?", which would be another question altogether, but that rephrasing might help illustrate what `docker service` does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale your application, you can run multiple instances of it (horizontal scaling) or you beef up the machine(s) that it runs on (vertical scaling). For the first, you would have to put a load balancer in front of your application so that the traffic is evenly distributed between the different instances. The idea is that those instances run on different hosts, so if one goes down, your application is still up. Some controlling instance (a Kubernetes service, for example) will notice that one of your instances has gone south and won't direct any more traffic to it. Nowadays, with all the cloud stuff going on, this is typically the way to go.

You don't need Kubernetes for such a setup, but you're right, this would be a typical use case for it. At least if you run your application in a Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Once use case is running on Docker swarm which consists of n number of nodes in your swarm cluster. You can run replicas of your application on the swarm cluster with a load balancer/reverse proxy to load balance your setup. If any one of the nodes goes down the application can still run.

But the exact use case for running multiple instances is **scalabilty**. Suppose you know that one instance of your app can serve 10000 users (Assume Bank authentication) at a time.
If you want your application to serve 50K users just run 5 replicas(using docker service create) .