# Do service and container mean the same thing?

Tags: docker

I have come across the word service in many Docker documentations. Does service mean a container? By definition, a container is supposed to perform only one task. Are service and container then to be understood as synonymous?

Comment: Although no accepted answer exists, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408493/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-service-and-docker-container/43408720   and [What is a container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container#:~:text=A%20Docker%20container%20image%20is,tools%2C%20system%20libraries%20and%20settings.)  A container can "everything needed to run an application", which i more than "only 1 task".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Docker Service and Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408493/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-service-and-docker-container)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "service" is originally linked with [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/)

> A service is the definition of the tasks to execute on the manager or worker nodes.
> It is the central structure of the swarm system and the primary root of user interaction with the swarm.
>
> When you create a service, you specify which container image to use and which commands to execute inside running containers.

As mentioned in the [Container Network Model](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a77317882d010b884a9101c6ad0b2d7db141082f/libnetwork/docs/design.md#the-container-network-model):

> **Endpoint** represents a Service Endpoint. It provides the connectivity for services exposed by a container in a network with other services provided by other containers in the network.
>
> Since Endpoint represents a Service and not necessarily a particular container, Endpoint has a global scope within a cluster.

That illustrates a service is not a container, but a way to describe and manage a set of containers (0 to n).
From "[How services work](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/)":

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/images/services-diagram.png]